# Data gives me {url: ......} but Data.url gives me undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object called data which stores URL. If I **resolve(data)** it *returns {url: .....}* but when I **resolve(data.url)** it return *undefined*.

I will elaborate a bit more : -

```
request(options, function(error, response, data) {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      console.log('data --->', data); //returns {"url": "abc.com"}
      console.log('data.url --->', data.url); //returns undefined
      return resolve(data);
    });
```

It would be great if I can know the reason behind the issue as I am unable to figure it out.
Thank you

Comment: I bet that data is actually a string `"{"url": "abc.com"}"` and not an object.

Comment: its because data is a json string. you need to convert it to javascript object using `JSON.parse(data)` before accessing `data.url`

Comment: try this `console.log(data['url']);`

Comment: add [`json:true`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback) to options, problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet that `data` is actually a string `"{"url": "abc.com"}"` and not an object.

You should convert it into an object using something like `data = JSON.parse(data)`.

Or if you want to increase the robustness of your code, then `data = parse(data)`, where:

```
function parse(str) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    }
    catch (error) {
        return {};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It was a string actually. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the data after checking its type. `data` coming from API is of type `string` you are accessing the property from `string` which doesn't exist.

```
request(options, function(error, response, data) {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      if(typeof(data) == "string"){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
      }
      console.log('data --->', data); //returns {"url": "abc.com"}
      console.log('data.url --->', data.url); //returns undefined
      return resolve(data);
    });
```